# keyless public read-only access on gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I was wondering if it was possible to configure gitolite to let anybody clone a repository without having to do the whole public key song and dance.

Obviously I don't want people to be able to change the repo without a key first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options for public Git access:

1. **Git protocol**, handled by [*git daemon*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html):

   ```
   git daemon --base-path /srv/git
   ```

   If you run *git daemon* with `--base-path /srv/git` on example.com, then if you later try to pull `git://example.com/hello.git`, *git daemon* will interpret the path as `/srv/git/hello.git`.

   For multiple "vhosts", `--interpolated-path /srv/git/%H/%D` would map the same to `/srv/git/example.com/hello.git`.

   The `--user-path` option gives "userdir"-like translation of `git://example.com/~user/hello.git` to `/home/user/hello.git`.

   You can run *git daemon* [from xinetd](http://sprunge.us/OLCf), or as a background daemon using the `--detach` option (`sudo -u nobody git daemon --detach <other options>`).
2. **Smart HTTP**, which requires a web server: [instructions on Pro Git](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html)

   This is a bit more complicated to set up, but crosses proxies and firewalls more easily (which may be an advantage in certain environments).

   It is possible to push over HTTP too – make sure you don't accidentally enable that.

Comment: and this wont interfere with the fact that the repo is already managed by gitolite? What happens if somebody is cloning with the public access and another person pushes with ssh at the same time?

Comment: @Chris: In Git, such operations are atomic, as in most modern VCSs. Besides, Gitolite doesn't deal with the inner structure, it mostly manages user access. It is *very* common usage to have the same repository served over Gitproto, SSH (sometimes Gitolite, more often just user@host:path), and even HTTP.

Comment: Also, you can use the [special `daemon` user in the Gitolite configuration](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/2-admin.html#gwd) to automatically create the special `git-daemon-export-ok` file that `git daemon` looks for before allowing access through `git://` URLs.

Comment: Possible third option: How about making a read-only private key and put it up for download on a Web-site, then install the public key in Gitolite's keys directory ? -Would this be a security issue, or would Gitolite be able to handle it ?